# error running react-native application MaxBufferError: stderr maxBuffer exceeded

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

When I try to run any react-native application I don't come across this error, even when I've just created a new application!

Please help me! more error details:

```
C:\laragon\bin\nodejs\node-v18.16.0-win-x64\node.exe C:\Users\g\PhpstormProjects\Boleia\node_modules\react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1485 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE

MaxBufferError: stderr maxBuffer exceeded
    at PassThrough.<anonymous> (C:\Users\g\PhpstormProjects\Boleia\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\get-stream\index.js:41:19)
    at PassThrough.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:293:11)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at node:internal/streams/transform:182:12
    at PassThrough._transform (node:internal/streams/passthrough:46:3)
    at Transform._write (node:internal/streams/transform:175:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
```

I've tried unfortunately I couldn't solve this error, I've already tried to increase the maxBuffer when executing the react-native run android